# Add or active a code html in asp.net mvc

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have this:

```
<div class="display"> display</div>
<div class="hidden" style="display:none">hidden</div>
```

How can I change the style from `display:none` to `display:block` in my code in asp.net mvc?

```
<div class="display"> display</div>
<div class="hidden">hidden</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you mentioning asp.net-mvc ? if you need to make link visibility conditional on a server - then you can use something like <div class="hidden" style="@(condition_or_boolean_var ? "display:none" : "")">hidden</div>.

Comment: sorry because i need make a code html by asp.net

Comment: your question is not clear enough, what is it you want to really achieve? Do you want to pass `html` tags to your page from code behind or you just want to know how to write `html` in `asp.net mvc`.

Comment: ex: I have a code <a href="#"> example</a> i want insert it by code asp.net look like php can do. <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> Sr i'm newbee, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your element an `id` and then use pure JavaScript or JQuery to do it.

```
<!-- Give id first -->
<div id="some-id" class="hidden" style="display:none">hidden</div>
```

**Pure JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('some-id').style.display = 'block';
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#some-id').css('display', 'block')
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to manipulate html codes by using c# like following;

```
<div class="hidden" @(isVisible ? "style='display:block'":"style='display:none'")>hidden</div>
```

`isVisible` is the c# variable. And you may write like following, too.

```
<div class="hidden" style="display:@(isVisible ? "block":"none")">hidden</div>
```

There are many different ways to do this. Read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor) for more detail.